# NSURLConnection do not launch

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, networking, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to create a very simple app which connects to an URL and gets the contents of that URL, in this case a simple xml document. My problem is that that the request never seems to gets sent.

I have created a new project(Foundation tool) which runs from a main file. I have set the 
delegate of the NSURLConnection to self and implemented the necessary delegate methods.
The problem is that these methods never get called. It doesn't matter if I change the URL
to some bogus one(as in the example below). 
It seems to me that the application finish launching without sending or waiting for the response.
Could it be that my application creates a thread for the request and then finishes without waiting for the response??
I know that the class is running since i get the NSLOG statements like "Created connection
" but no NSLOG statements from within the delegate methods.

What am I missing?

```
#import "NetworkController.h"
@implementation NetworkController

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {

    }   
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Calling dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void) performConnection
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                       @"http://www.test.php?some variables"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *connectionRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [url release];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:connectionRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (!theConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    }
    if(theConnection)
    {
        receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"Created connection.");

        NSLog(@"--------- Request submitted ---------");
        NSLog(@"receivedData: %@", receivedData);
    }

    [connectionRequest release];
}

#pragma mark NetworkController Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Received response: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Received response, connection retain count is %d",[connection retainCount]);
}

#pragma mark NetworkController Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Connection received data, retain count: %d", [connection retainCount]);
}

#pragma mark NetworkController Delegate
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"finished connection retain count:  %d", [connection retainCount]);}

#pragma mark NetworkController Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error receiving response: %@", error);
    [connection release];
}

@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NetworkController.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


    NetworkController *n = [[NetworkController alloc] init];
    n.performConnection;
    [n release];

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you POST your main function plase? The one where you instantiate NetworkManager.

Comment: Ditto what Pablo says, but I'm pretty certain you're not running your run loop...

Comment: My main  function looks like this:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NetworkController.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 
 NetworkController *n = [[NetworkController alloc] init];
 n.performConnection;
 [n release];
 
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

Comment: added main function to the question.

Answer (score 2):

First, the message syntax is:

```
[n performConnection];
```

What you have there is property access syntax. And since the method is typed as returning `void`, I wouldn't take it as guaranteed to work even on that level.

Anyway, the major problem is that you're using the asynchronous NSURLConnection API (good) but expecting synchronous behavior (bad). All the NSURLConnection methods return immediately, then work in the background, with the idea sending delegate messages to your network controller as things happen—but immediately after you finish setting everything up, you release the network controller (in turn leaking the connection, since you didn't `release` it in your `dealloc` method), then exit.

You need to run the run loop before you release the network controller, to give the connection time to send the request, read the response, and send the network controller some delegate messages. You also need to `cancel` and `release` the connection in the network controller's `dealloc` method.

Also, you need to make that NSMutableData variable an instance variable, since you need to be able to reach it from the delegate methods. Don't forget to release that, too, in your `dealloc` method (and `release` it and set it to `nil` in both of the delegate methods that indicate the connection is over).

Comment: +1, this is better then my answer. Plus we should tell him not to monkey with main manually, unless he knows what he is doing.

Comment: He's writing a command-line tool; putting at least some code in main is normal for such a program.

Comment: Aha, that did not occur to me.

Comment: You're right, Peter, the connection does count as an input source. I recall it not working properly in 10.4 tho, so maybe it's been changed. Anyway, I am deleting my answer because I didn't read his code closely enough and it has a lot of issues that I think your answer addresses.